# [iOS]: detect when view controller appears after back from another external app

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my escenario:

I have a view controller where the user can go to another application (Settings) when push a button in this way:

```
    -(void) goToSettings{
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
    }
```

So, this code open the app's screen settings and it shows in the upper left corner a legend like this:

> Back to myApplication

I wish to detect when the view controller where user push the button is active again. I know you can detect when app is active again with this method in the delegate file

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

But I need detect in specific the view controller. I have tried with `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` but It not works. Anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setup your view controller to listen for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(becomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Then add the `becomeActive:` method:

```
- (void)becomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // App is active again - do something useful
}
```

And be sure to remove the observer at the appropriate point.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Of course your app may become active again for lots of reasons, not just returning from the Settings app.